# How can I use a Twig variable in Assetics 'javascript' tag?

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

I'm using Assetic to include my scripts and need to pass the current locale. How would I do that?

```
{% javascripts
    '@MyBundle/Resources/public/components/moment/moment.js'
    '@MyBundle/Resources/public/components/moment/lang/' ~ app.request.locale ~ '.js'
 %}
```

String concatenation does not work and throws **Unexpected token "operator" of value "~"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use assetic's variables as described in [Ryan Weaver's answer here](https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/issues/136#issuecomment-17747960). The feature is kind of broken but will work in your case as you use the locale as variable.

> The answer is that only two variables work by default (locale and env,
>   and their values are preconfigued in Symfony:
>   https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/blob/master/DefaultValueSupplier.php#L31.

**config_dev.yml**

```
assetic:
    use_controller: false
```

**config.yml**

> You'll also need to set your assetic.variables.locale [...] to the
>   total possible combinations of your variable:

```
assetic:
    variables:
        locale:    [en,fr,de]
```

... then use them inside the javaScripts tag after invoking `assetic:dump`.

**template**

```
{% javascripts
     'bundles/my/components/{locale}.js'
%}
```

Comment: Thanks! Never thought, it would be that complicated. Basically it works, but unfortunately momentjs has no locale for "en" (like my application), just for "en-GB" and "en-US". So in the end I couldn't use this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround construction:

```html
{%set myScript = '@MyBundle/Resources/public/components/moment/lang/' ~ app.request.locale ~ '.js' %}

<script src="{{ asset(myScript) }}"></script>
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. It would be a more helpful answer if you provided explanation for your code for the benefit of future users.